# Export data to file

Tags: list-manipulation, files-and-directories

I have a function f[x,y,z,i] that returns the solutions {x1,y1,z1} for each step "i".
I would like to use a repeating command  (such as Do[...]) to get the outputs of this function f saved in a file. More specifically, I thought using something like Do[f[x,y,z,i],{i,1,10,1}] combined with Save, but I do not know how to combine these two commands with the interation of "i"

Comment: How about: allf = Table[f[x, y, z, i], {i, 1, 10, 1}]; Export["fileName.m", allf]

Comment: Great, that works!!